# Bluetooth devices name are not showing up (Giving null)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

i hope you're doing great, I'm having an issue that when i search for bluetooth devices, i get the some of devices with name but most of the devices does not provide their name and those devices provide their name in Iphone's bluetooth, I tried some solutions

1- first connect to device then get the name in delegate (peripheralDidUpdateName) , in this i get response from few devices while other devices stuck in connecting state 
2- i tried to search for devices with some delays so i could find the name but still stuck in same issue

```
extension LandingPage : CBCentralManagerDelegate , CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

        switch (central.state) {
        case .poweredOff :
            print("bluetooth is off ")
            self.mainPeripheral.removeAll()
        case .poweredOn :
            print("bluetooth is on ")
            manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
         }
     }
return
```

Actual Result :

```
<CBPeripheral: 0x282d090e0, identifier = D94CC0E6-0340-8406-4688-C38D593F3201, name = (null), state = disconnected>
<CBPeripheral: 0x282d0d040, identifier = 04F5A632-3FBE-47A6-C6A6-2DDF9975184C, name = (null), state = disconnected>
<CBPeripheral: 0x282d0d040, identifier = CE0FD194-7E7D-4004-C50B-049C2958F495, name = (null), state = disconnected>
<CBPeripheral: 0x282d0d040, identifier = E780781F-7D6B-8052-9743-ECFEB5C534C8, name = (null), state = disconnected>
```

Expected:

```
<CBPeripheral: 0x282d0c0a0, identifier = 803732A6-31F9-A740-EC6A-8C9E3CDE8F71, name = Lefun, state = disconnected>
<CBPeripheral: 0x282d0d040, identifier = 6C19BC9F-1891-82DE-51D6-0C0E371F2E03, name = LH719, state = disconnected>
```

Comment: where is actual result and expected?

Comment: Actual Output :  <CBPeripheral: 0x282d0d040, identifier = 04639373-E624-4608-523B-0426FD51F03A, name = (null), state = disconnected>

Comment: Expected : <CBPeripheral: 0x282d0c0a0, identifier = 803732A6-31F9-A740-EC6A-8C9E3CDE8F71, name = Lefun-Band , state = disconnected>

Comment: Instead of `options: nil`, set options. Advertisement Data come in chunks. So sometimes it doesn't have the name, then later it has it, etc. Let them appear a few times (for the same device).

Comment: i just tried with :   manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])

Comment: so now i'm receiving packets so fast but still name is null , and few devices have name only